# Как подключиться к всплывающему окну с помощью selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("site_path")
```

С помощью этого кода подключился к сайту, получил такое [image: такое окно]

с помощью `f12` получил такую такую информацию по html коду

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:**

Как подключиться к этим полям, или это невозможно и стоит защита от такого действия?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вы можете передать логин и пароль в url.**

```
http://login:password@mydomain.ru/
```

**Или, ввести данные в поля вот так:**

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.url.com/')
wait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present())
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.send_keys('username')
alert.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
alert.send_keys('password')
alert.accept()
```

Comment: Благодарю, не пробовал то, что ты добавил второй частью, но http://login:password@mydomain.ru/ со второй попытки сработало